# Why is my property notification not triggering?

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged

I have an hierarchy of classes. The pertinent bits are included below. I was expecting that when FilterCritetionInteger.CriterionValue is changed, via WPF binding, that I would get a notification in my FilterCriterionCollection. But, while the FilterCriterionInteger.CriterionValue setter is called, the FilterCriterionCollection.Criterion_PropertyChanged method is never called.

Apparently I am misunderstanding something, or have something connected incorrectly. I'm just not finding it. Why is my notification not happening? (Please let me know if there is more context needed, anywhere.)

**ViewModelBase**

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler pcHandler = this.PropertyChanged;

    if (pcHandler != null)
    {
      PropertyChangedEventArgs args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
      pcHandler(this, args);
     }
  }  
}
```

**FilterCriterionBase**

```
public abstract class FilterCriterionBase : ViewModelBase
{
  public abstract bool IsValid { get; }
}
```

**FilterCriterionInteger**

```
public class FilterCriterionInteger : FilterCriterionBase
{
  private string _criterionValue = "0";
  public string CriterionValue
  {
    get { return _criterionValue; }
    set
    {
      _criterionValue = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("IsValid");
    }
  }

  public int? MaxValue { get; private set; } = null;

  public override bool IsValid
  {
    get
    {
      if (int.TryParse(_criterionValue, out int i))
      {
        if (MaxValue.HasValue && (i > MaxValue)) return false;
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

**FilterCriterionCollection**

```
public class FilterCriteriaCollection : ViewModelBase
{
  public FilterCriteriaCollection()
  {
    Criteria.CollectionChanged += Criteria_CollectionChanged;
  }

  ~FilterCriteriaCollection()
  {
    Criteria.CollectionChanged -= Criteria_CollectionChanged;
  }

  public ObservableCollection<FilterCriterionBase> Criteria { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<FilterCriterionBase>();

  private void Criteria_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    switch (e.Action)
    {
      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
        foreach (FilterCriterionBase fb in e.NewItems)
        {
          fb.PropertyChanged += Criterion_PropertyChanged;
        }
        break;

      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
        foreach (FilterCriterionBase fb in e.NewItems)
        {
          fb.PropertyChanged -= Criterion_PropertyChanged;
        }
        break;
    }
  }

  private bool _isValid;
  public bool IsValid
  {
    get { return _isValid; }
    private set { _isValid = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsValid"); }
  }

  private void Criterion_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    using (FilterCriterionBase criterion = sender as FilterCriterionBase)
    {
      switch (e.PropertyName)
      {
        case "IsValid":
          {
            bool isvalid = true;

            foreach(FilterCriterionBase fcb in Criteria)
            {
              isvalid = fcb.IsValid;
              if (!isvalid) break;
            }

            IsValid = isvalid;
            break;
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the string says "isValid" but is in the CriterionValue property

Comment: @Charlie - That's a call to trigger the re-evaluation of the "IsValid" property. "IsValid" with a capital "I" is the public name of the property. I don't see anything wrong there. Could you be more specific?

Comment: try adding this also: OnPropertyChanged("CriterionValue"). The reevaluating is fine but if you bind on CriterionValue then there must be a changedevent for CriterionValue.

Comment: The change comes through a WPF binding. In my scenario, the change would never come internally, so there is nobody to notify. I just need to re-evaluate the validity once a user changes the value.

Comment: @DigitalCamel On a side note: Why do you have a `using` statement there? You are going to dispose the event sender in your event handler? That doesn't look right.

Comment: @Progman - An excellent question. I'm not sure why I did that. The FilterCriterionBase doesn't implement IDisposable, so I'm not sure it has any effect, at all. I suppose, at the moment, I was intending to clean up my reference to the sender? I will fix that. I don't think it has bearing on my issue, though.

Answer (score 1):

So, as it turns out, I am a moron. The code, above, does need a little tweaking but it is, in general, sound. My primary issue was that I had some leftover code, in my testing sandbox, from testing some JSON serialization/deserialization. I realized, after much head banging, that I was sending deserialized objects that had lost their event notification context and, therefore, were no longer in the loop.

Would it be proper protocol to just delete this post, since it doesn't really require an answer beyond double checking your inputs...?